# Get a specific value from JSON data using MongoDB python

Tags: python, json, database, mongodb

I am trying to get a specific value from a nested JSON object. I've tried the following but in all cases I get all the specific values from all the nested objects.
I would like to get the specific price from one artist in this case with the id: 1176704.

```
collection_name = dbname["Tattooparlor"]
```

---

```
cus_details = collection_name.aggregate([{"$match": {"artists._id": 1176704}}])
print(cus_details)

for r in cus_details:
   print(r)
```

---

or

```
for r in collection_name.find({"_id": 9392991}, {"artists._id": 1176704}):
   print(r)
   for x in r["artists"]:
       print(x["price"])
```

---

In all cases it returns 1779, 2730, 4530 or the full object and I just want it to return 1779.

My JSON object looks like this

[image: JSON object]

Comment: Try [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection.

Comment: @prasad_ I get this error trying $elemMatch "$elemMatch is not allowed in this atlas tier"

Comment: Its probably means that your Atlas Cluster tier (e.g., M0, etc.) has some limited features. You can lookup Atlas documentation about _limitations_. Maybe this might work: [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this? You have to find the artist's id then print out his/her price.

```
for result in collection_name.find({"_id": 9392991}):
    for arr in r["artists"]:
       if arr["_id"] == 1176704:
          print(arr["price"])
```

Comment: I get this error

for field_value in r["artists"]["_id"]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: See my edit. Didn't realize artists is an array of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

if you try by limiting only price field
collection_name.find({"_id": 9392991}, {"artists._id": 1176704},{price:1})